# Timeout with exec on javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, timeout

I have 2 files which I'm writing JS on: learn and test. On learn I'm tryin to create an asyc function that will do the following:
Develop a ‘function declaration’ called ‘`qAsync`'
Returns an object (built via constructor) that consists of two keys:

1. ‘`doAsync`’: function: returns `setTimeout` function that can be used using async/await syntax
2. ‘`exec`’ : function that uses the `doAsync` function to print something after 11.5 seconds
3. ‘`desc`’ : string: description of what doAsync/exec() are doing and how to use it

but I'm not sure if my code is correct since my test file doesn't recognize my exec for some reason. My code on learn.js:

```
function qAsync(){
      const doAsync = new doAsync(11500);
      this.desc= "in order to wait 11.5 sec, call qAsync which calls asyncFun"
      let exec= doAsync.exec(("hello after 11.5 sec"));
      return (exec,doAsync);
}
  
let doAsync = async function (ms) {
    return await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

On test.js:

```
function test4(){
    let test = qAsync();
    alert("first let us decribe the function:\n" + test.desc);
    alert("now we will run exec.");

    test.exec(); //doesn't work and calls on built in exec and not mine
}
```

How can I get my test to work and do you think I should improve my qAsync?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232402/discussion-on-question-by-yuki1112-timeout-with-exec-on-javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered thanks to comments:
learn.js:

```
function qAsync(){
      this.doAsync = function (ms) {
         return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      }
      this.desc = "in order to wait 11.5 sec, call exec which calls doAsync, and see the print in the console"
      this.exec =  async function () {
          await this.doAsync(11500);
          console.log("did you see this after 11.5 sec?");
      }
  }
```

test.js:

```
async function test4(){
    let test = new qAsync();
    alert("first let us describe the function:\n"+test.desc);
    alert("now we will run exec.");
    await test.exec();
}
```